# sort array of objects with alpha numeric property(First alphabets A-Z and then numbers 0-9)

Tags: javascript

Am looking to sort an array which has alphabets and numbers

```
inputArray = ["1", "a2", "c", "4", "b1", 2];
expectedArray = ["a2", "b1", "c", 1, 2, 4];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an alphanumeric and a numeric array. Then sort them before concatinating them.

```js
const inputArray = ["1", "a2", "c", "4", "b1", 2];
let alpha = [], num = [];

inputArray.map( (element) => {
  if( parseInt(element) == element ) num.push( parseInt( element ));
  else alpha.push( element );
});

const expectedArray = [...alpha.sort(), ...num.sort()];
console.log( expectedArray );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the values into non digits and digits and apply sorting with groups.

```js
const match = value => value.toString().match(/^(\D*)(\d*)$/).slice(1);

var data = ["1", "a2", "c", "4", "b1", 2];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    const
        aa = match(a),
        bb = match(b);

    return (aa[0] === '') - (bb[0] === '') // move only digits to end
        || aa[0].localeCompare(bb[0])      // sort by letters
        || (aa[1] || 0) - (bb[1] || 0);    // sort by digits
});

console.log(...data);
```